# Wrong Tax calculation when creating order from Admin

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, shipping-tax

I have an issue I can't solve from normal TAX panel.

I have all my shipping prices setted without tax in the admin and they are  calculated in the right way in the cart and checkout page in frontend. Please see image
[image: Checkout good tax calculation]

As you can see from the picture the shipping cost is 8.20 + 22% tax and is correctly showed as 10 €.
Shipping Tax  are also well included in Tax (Tasse) row.

Now the issue I have is that if i create an order from the admin using the same customer/address/product/shipping method, the Shphipping and Handleing are wrong!! They are without tax (also if shipping method shows them including tax) 
See the image below
[image: Admin create order]

If I click 2 times on the Radio Button of the shipping method, the Shipping and Handling value it gets right.
So once I click for a second time on the choosen shipping method radio button I get the right value of 10€ (instead of the wrong 8.20€) just as on the front page(see first image).

So it looks like Magento doen't add tax on the first click, then on the second it does.

*Is that a bug of Magento 1.8 ?  How can i overwright the tax calculation for the admin block?*

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution for this

Please add following line of code into `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`

Before that override the model class in local directory or copy file into local `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`.

```
public function initFromOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
```

following code before quote save

```
$this->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
$this->getQuote()->save()
```